# How to send data with Angular to spring boot application..?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have made an login application in angular 2 and its working...

My **`app.ts`**

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {DemoForm} from './form';
//import {FormBuilder, ControlGroup} from "angular2/angular2";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <demo-form></demo-form>
  `,
  directives:[DemoForm]
})
class AppComponent {
  constructor(){}
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,[]);
```

and my **`form.ts`**

```
import {Component, View, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({  
  selector: 'demo-form'
})
@View({
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
  <div>
    <form #f="form" (submit)="onSubmit(f)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id">id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-control="id" placeholder="id" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-control="name" placeholder="name" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    submitted : {{submitted|json}}
  </div>  
  `
})
export class DemoForm {
  private submitted:object = {};
  onSubmit(f) {
    this.submitted = f.value;
  }
}
```

and when submitted i my username and password will in json format as

submitted : `{ "id": "Test", "name": "password" }`

Now i have to  send the username and password from my Angular application to `spring boot controller`...
so that i can use that username and password in my back-end...

i have no idea how to start it.. so if you have some tutorials and or simple plunker example that can help me with this.. share it

Comment: I would suggest you read about client server architectures and http first. :)

Comment: Here is a link to the relevant part of Angular's introduction tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html If you haven't done it yet I would highly suggest you to do it :)

Comment: your spring boot app is just like any other backend: it exposes endpoints, that you may call from anywhere and anything that supports http requests

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to find an A-Z document on how to do it. You can learn pieces at a time.

Basically, you need to have:

- some method of input: [Angular 2 Forms](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_forms.htm)
- a way to send that input to the backend: [Angular 2 HTTP Services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#sts=Providing%20HTTP%20services)
- a secure login on the backend: [Spring Security Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

**Other links**

- Spring + Angular2: https://github.com/borysn/spring-boot-angular2
- Angular 2 login: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: Please consider providing another link for the angular forms.